# Study on function $ \phi_{p}(x) = x_1^{p_1}\cdots x_n^{p_n} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $$ S^{n-1} = \{ x = (x_1,\dots,x_n ); x_k \geq 0; \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x_k=1  $$
Defined the functional 
$$ \phi_{p}(x) = x_1^{p_1}\cdots x_n^{p_n} $$
where $ x \in S^{n-1}$. It is known (see [53]) that if $p_i \geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i=1 $ then the functional $\phi_p$ is concave and  has a unique maximum point at $p=(p_1,\dots,p_n)$ i.e.,
$$ \max_{x\in S^{n-1}} \phi_p(x) = p_1^{p_1}\cdots p_n^{p_n} $$
here for $p_i = 0$ we have assumed that $p_i^{p_i} = 1$.

[53] Rockafellar R. T. Convex analysis, Mir, Moscow, 1973. (I found the book but it was written in 1972. As far as i read that book, i did not find on the discussion on the function $\phi(x)$)

I really need to understand the function $\phi$ and how actually he get the statement $ \max_{x\in S^{n-1}} \phi_p(x) = p_1^{p_1}\cdots p_n^{p_n} $

My next question: is the statement 
$$ \max_{y_1+\cdots+y_n <1} \phi_p(y)\leq \max_{x\in S^{n-1}} \phi_p(x)  $$
valid for $y_i\geq0$ where $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i=1 $.

Comment: You're trying to  take the maximum over a non-compact set. This doesn't exist in general (take n=1 to see why). So you need to replace the $max$ with a $sup$. But then it is trivial to show that the $sup$ is $p_1^{p_1}\dots p_n^{p_n}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Nitrogen . If you have some time, could you explain  how actually to get $\max_{x\in S^{n-1}} \phi_p(x) = p_1^{p_1}\cdots p_n^{p_n}$.

Why you say it is trivial to show that the $sup$ is $p_1^{p_1}\cdots p_n^{p_n}$